# How to add jwilder/nginx-proxy to my docker-compose and solve for container errors?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a web app container and an nginx container used to proxy traffic to my web app. I'm using docker image `jwilder/nginx-proxy` for my proxy. Not sure if I have configured things in my docker-compose well. My two containers seem to be getting errors that are possibly related to each other?

`docker-compose`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/web/Dockerfile
    image: web_app
    command: /start
    restart: always
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/app/static
      - mediafiles:/app/media
    env_file:  
      - ./.env/.prod
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db #not shown in this file for brevity
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=localhost
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8000


  nginx-proxy:
    image: nginxproxy/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - staticfiles:/app/static
      - mediafiles:/app/media
    depends_on:
      - web


volumes:
  postgres_data:
  mediafiles:
  staticfiles:
```

`nginx-proxy` container log:

```
Info: running nginx-proxy version 1.0.1-6-gc4ad18f

Setting up DH Parameters..

forego      | starting dockergen.1 on port 5000

forego      | starting nginx.1 on port 5100

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: using the "epoll" event method

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: nginx/1.21.6

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: OS: Linux 4.19.128-microsoft-standard

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker processes

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 25

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 26

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 27

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 28

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 29

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 30

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 31

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 32

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 33

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 34

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 35

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 36

dockergen.1 | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 Template error: open /etc/nginx/certs: no such file or directory

dockergen.1 | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 Generated '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' from 3 containers

dockergen.1 | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 Running 'nginx -s reload'

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: signal 1 (SIGHUP) received from 38, reconfiguring

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: reconfiguring

dockergen.1 | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 Watching docker events

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: using the "epoll" event method

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker processes

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 43

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 44

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 45

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 46

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 47

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 48

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 49

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 50

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 51

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 52

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 53

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: start worker process 54

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 25#25: gracefully shutting down

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 26#26: gracefully shutting down

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 27#27: gracefully shutting down

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 28#28: gracefully shutting down

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 29#29: gracefully shutting down

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 30#30: gracefully shutting down

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 33#33: gracefully shutting down

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 26#26: exiting

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 31#31: gracefully shutting down

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 36#36: gracefully shutting down

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 28#28: exiting

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 25#25: exiting

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 29#29: exiting

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 27#27: exiting

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 32#32: gracefully shutting down

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 33#33: exiting

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 30#30: exiting

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 26#26: exit

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 31#31: exiting

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 36#36: exiting

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 29#29: exit

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 25#25: exit

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 28#28: exit

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 32#32: exiting

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 27#27: exit

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 33#33: exit

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 31#31: exit

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 30#30: exit

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 36#36: exit

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 32#32: exit

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 35#35: gracefully shutting down

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 35#35: exiting

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 35#35: exit

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 34#34: gracefully shutting down

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 34#34: exiting

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 34#34: exit

dockergen.1 | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 Template error: open /etc/nginx/certs: no such file or directory

dockergen.1 | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 34

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: worker process 29 exited with code 0

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: worker process 30 exited with code 0

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: worker process 34 exited with code 0

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: signal 29 (SIGIO) received

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 31

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: worker process 31 exited with code 0

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: signal 29 (SIGIO) received

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 36

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: worker process 36 exited with code 0

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: signal 29 (SIGIO) received

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 25

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: worker process 25 exited with code 0

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: worker process 28 exited with code 0

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: signal 29 (SIGIO) received

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 33

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: worker process 26 exited with code 0

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: worker process 27 exited with code 0

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: worker process 33 exited with code 0

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: worker process 35 exited with code 0

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: signal 29 (SIGIO) received

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 26

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 32

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: worker process 32 exited with code 0

nginx.1     | 2022/05/20 14:24:00 [notice] 20#20: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
```

my web container log:

```
[2022-05-20 14:24:03 +0000] [12] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0

[2022-05-20 14:24:03 +0000] [12] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (12)

[2022-05-20 14:24:03 +0000] [12] [INFO] Using worker: gthread

[2022-05-20 14:24:03 +0000] [14] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14

[2022-05-20 14:24:03 +0000] [15] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15

[2022-05-20 14:24:03 +0000] [16] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16
```

EDIT: I have updated the logs.